# When I am calling VSTS API for uploading file with special characters,My filename is getting truncated and all special caharacters are ignored

Tags: java, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am calling VSTS API to upload file attachment with file name having special characters. But the file name is getting truncated and all characters starting from first special characters gets truncated.e.g.if filename is `file2367@#$$$##`
then corresponding uploaded file is `file2367@` and rest all characters are truncated.
Below is the code I am using for uploading attachments.

```
public String uploadAttachment(InputStream inputStream, String fileName) throws Exception {

    fileName=URLEncoder.encode(fileName,"UTF-8");
    logger.info("******file name is******* :" + fileName);

    String query = getBaseUrl() + "_apis/wit/attachments?filename=" + fileName;
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(query);

    httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;api-version=1.0");
    httpPost.setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(inputStream));
    String authHeader = getAuthHeader();
    httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", authHeader);
    httpPost = ProxyConnectionUtility.getInstance().configureProxy(httpPost);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    logger.info("VSTS attachment response:" + response);
    HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
    String strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity, "UTF-8");
    int iStatusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (iStatusCode != 200 && iStatusCode != 201) {
        throw new Exception("Record could not be updated due to the error: " + strResponse);
    }

    return strResponse;
}
```